# SQL for the below mentioned scenario

Tags: sql, window-functions, amazon-athena

I have a table called events in AWS Athena with columns like user_id, event_name, session_id, epoch_utc, event_date, order_id, email, etc.

These events are the events for users who are doing Purchase online. Typically the flow is like PageView, AddToCart and Purchase

For one particular user_id, we have the below sample data for last week with few columns showing them in descending order of epoch_utc:

```
row no user_id session_id event_name epoch_utc      email             event_id 

1      ABC     f23_0      AddToCart  1677610977795  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
2      ABC     f23_0      AddToCart  1677610977740  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
3      ABC     f23_0      PageView   1677610358276  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
4      ABC     f23_0      AddToCart  1677610358119  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
5      ABC     f35_1      AddToCart  1677539280686  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
6      ABC     f35_1      ViewContent1677539280684  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
7      ABC     f35_1      PageView   1677539254195  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
```

I want to update this table or create a new table out of this table where I want to add a new Purchase event row for a particular user in a given session, out of many events, there are 2 events PageView and then AddToCart in ascending order.

I added Row no. column to just explain the example. In table, the column row number does not exist.

So my final output should be like this

```
1      ABC     f23_0      AddToCart  1677610977795  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
2      ABC     f23_0      Purchase   1677610977741  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
3      ABC     f23_0      AddToCart  1677610977740  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
4      ABC     f23_0      PageView   1677610358276  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
5      ABC     f23_0      AddToCart  1677610358119  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
6      ABC     f35_1      Purchase   1677539280687  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
7      ABC     f35_1      AddToCart  1677539280686  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
8      ABC     f35_1      ViewContent1677539280684  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
9      ABC     f35_1      PageView   1677539254195  abc@hotmail.com.  <unique_id>
```

So 2 rows are added in the dataset for a particular user, for a session, added a Purchase event row with epoch_utc slightly larger than AddToCart and other column values copied from AddToCart row.

Basically I am trying to add missing Purchase events in a session which has many events, but PageView and AddToCart in a time increasing order.

What SQL do I need to create a new temp table out of the original table?

Comment: Just to get it right, are you trying to create additional rows? Can you share what you've attempted till now?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to create additional rows. Pratik

Answer (score 0):

The final answer could look something like this, which involves multiple passes.

Each pass adds a particular event type that's missing. So 2 passes for adding Purchase and PageView events and another pass to copy just the existing data into the new table.

Step 1: Create the destination table with same schema.

Step 2: Create 'PurchaseEvent' records in the new table. See below for how.

Step 3: Create 'PageView' records in the new table. See below for how. You can combine Step 1 and 2, if the epoch time logic is the same for both.

Step 4: Copy data from existing table to new table using the same method as below.

```
WITH Ranking_Order 
AS (
SELECT user_id, 
event_name, 
session_id, 
epoch_utc, 
event_date, 
order_id, 
email,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, session_id ORDER BY  event_date) as rank
FROM source_table
)



INSERT INTO new_destination_table 
SELECT user_id, 
'PurchaseEvent', 
session_id, 
epoch_utc + 10 //(Can be decided by you), 
event_date, 
order_id, 
email 
FROM source_table
where rank = 2 // RANK = 2 implies there are multiple events in the session for that user, one for pageview and then addtocart.
and event_name = 'AddToCart' // check that the latest event is addtocart.
```

Comment: This query only checks if there was an AddToCart event. I am looking to add new row with Purchase event only when a session for a user has both events - first PageView and then AddToCart. So need to check for these 2 events in the given order.

Comment: Assume there are multiple users with multiple session_ids in the events table.

Comment: @azaveri7 Got it. Have edited my query to account for the information you've shared.